# I wanted to add WordPress Product detail page for mobile version

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I wanted to edit the code of **woocommerce_single_product_summary**. Can you please help me out with where I can find the Html of this hook?

I wanted to change the position of the element in the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already solved the issue, but you can use something like this to remove the hook and add a new hook with the new priority
`remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'function_you_want_to_reorder', priority number);`

`add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'function_you_want_to_reorder', new priority number);`